# Need help to make Mac .sh script in order to remove Recovered files in Trash

Tags: macos, bash, sh

I was trying to make a mac sh script in order to remove "Recovered files" folder created by Logitech's mouse software in Trash.

When I input `ls ~/.Trash/Recovered\ files`, I got these in Terminal:

```
com.logitech.gkeysdk.501    com.logitech.lcdmon.501
```

I would like to make this script to remove the "Recovered files" folder in this way:

If detects only these two files (com.logitech*) in "Recovered files", then remove "Recovered files".

Else, do not remove the folder.

So I made a script like this:

```
EXPECTED="com.logitech.gkeysdk.501  com.logitech.lcdmon.501"
lslogitech=$(ls ~/.Trash/Recovered\ files)

export print=$(lslogitech)
echo "print=$print"

if [ $(print) = "EXPECTED"]; then
  echo "Delete Recovered files in Trash"
  rm -rf ~/.Trash/Recovered\ files*
else
  echo "There are other files in Recovered files"
fi
```

But it doesn't work.
It's my first time to write this thing. Any help would be appreciative!

Comment: *"it doesn't work"*.. what happens when you run it?

Comment: `$(print)` should probably be `${print}` or just `$print`. In many shell syntax in the form of `$(..cmd..)` is for cmd-substitution. AND most systems have a cmd named `print`, so why not use a more meaningful var name like foundFiles or something like that. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably more along the lines you want:

```
EXPECTED="com.logitech.gkeysdk.501  com.logitech.lcdmon.501"
lslogitech=$(ls ~/.Trash/Recovered\ files)

for TRASH_FILE in $lslogitech ; do
    for EXP_FILE in $EXPECTED ; do
        if [ "$TRASH_FILE" == "$EXP_FILE" ] ; then
            rm -f ~/.Trash/Recovered\ files/$TRASH_FILE
        fi
    done
done

rmdir ~/.Trash/Recovered\ files &> /dev/null || echo "There are other files in Recovered files"
```

This loops through your `~/.Trash/Recovered\ files` directory and removes any files listed in the EXPECTED list.  It then attempts to silently remove the directory and issues the echo only if it fails.

OR, more concisely:

```
EXPECTED="com.logitech.gkeysdk.501  com.logitech.lcdmon.501"
TRASH_DIR="~/.Trash/Recovered\ files"

for TRASH_FILE in $(eval ls "$TRASH_DIR") ; do
    for EXP_FILE in $EXPECTED ; do
        [ "$TRASH_FILE" == "$EXP_FILE" ] && eval rm -f $TRASH_DIR/$TRASH_FILE
    done
done

eval rmdir $TRASH_DIR &> /dev/null || echo "There are other files in $TRASH_DIR"
```

*Note:  The eval is needed to expand `~` into your home directory path name*

**UPDATE:** This solution adds a search for multiple .Trash directories

```
EXPECTED="com.logitech.gkeysdk.501  com.logitech.lcdmon.501"

ls -d ~/.Trash/Recovered\ files* | while read TRASH_DIR ; do
    for TRASH_FILE in $(ls "$TRASH_DIR") ; do
        for EXP_FILE in $EXPECTED ; do
            [ "$TRASH_FILE" == "$EXP_FILE" ] && rm -f "$TRASH_DIR"/"$TRASH_FILE"
        done
    done
    rmdir "$TRASH_DIR" &> /dev/null || echo "There are other files in $TRASH_DIR"
done
```

Comment: Thanks Donovan! It works well!
If the "Recovered files" wasn't removed, there will be another folder called "Recovered files #1" in Trash after next boot. And #2, #3, etc... Do you know how to make the script check them all?

Comment: You would probably want to add another outer loop that goes through `~/.Trash/Recovered\ files*`, setting TRASH_DIR on each iteration.  I leave that as an exercise for you, given my example above. :)  Let me know if you need help.

Comment: Sorry, Donovan.

Because I don't know how to make a code box in here. I put the code [right here](http://pastebin.com/0P4imn1a).
I can only come up with this idea. But I'm sure it won't work, because there are some problem in "for TRASH_FILE in $(eval ls "$TRASH_DIR") ; do". Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Updated the answer with a solution for you.

Comment: Thanks! It's very perfect. I have one last question. How can I do to "EXPECTED=" if I want to make "EXPECTED" = either com.logitech.gkeysdk.501, com.logitech.lcdmon.501 or both or empty?
I made EXPECTED like this: EXPECTED="com.logitech.gkeysdk.501  com.logitech.lcdmon.501" || "com.logitech.gkeysdk.501" || "com.logitech.lcdmon.501" || "" But I found out when I have more than three items, it's gonna be a hard work. As sometimes ".DS_Store" is in the folder.

Comment: You shouldn't need to do that.  It will check any file in the EXPECTED list, so just add .DS_Store to the list and it should work.